# How do I symlink each of the files in one directory to another directory?

Tags: linux, mac, command-line, bash

If I have a directory `/foo` with a few files in it, how do I symlink each entry in `/foo` into `/bar/`?

For instance, if `/foo` has the files `a`, `b` and `c`, I want to create three symlinks:

- `/bar/a -> /foo/a`
- `/bar/b -> /foo/b`
- `/bar/c -> /foo/c`

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to symlink bar to foo?

Comment: The actual application of this is that I installed a program and would like to move its executables to a standard folder in my $PATH rather than add the installed one to the path.

Comment: It seems like it would be a better idea to just configure it with `--prefix=`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use (GNU) `cp` with the `--symbolic-link` option:

```
prompt$ mkdir foo
prompt$ cd foo
prompt$ touch a b c
prompt$ mkdir ../bar
prompt$ cd ../bar
prompt$ cp --symbolic-link ../foo/* .
prompt$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 hlovdal hlovdal 8 Jun 12 16:24 a -> ../foo/a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 hlovdal hlovdal 8 Jun 12 16:24 b -> ../foo/b
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 hlovdal hlovdal 8 Jun 12 16:24 c -> ../foo/c
prompt$
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly the solution. Awesome!

Comment: This is very perfect.

Comment: any way to make this apply for directories as well? When I run this I get warning "cp: omitting directory './baz'"

Comment: @solidau Answer of PausedUntilFurtherNotice. does it.

Answer (score 25):

Give this a try:

```
ln -s /foo/* /bar
```

The source directory, as specified in the question, is `/foo`. Note that it must be fully specified (i.e. starting at the root directory), so other examples would look like this:

```
ln -s /some/dir/with/baz/* destdir
ln -s /dir/to/link/from/* /dir/to/link/to
ln -s $PWD/stuff/* more/stuff
```

Comment: does this even work?

Comment: @root.ctrlc: You have to specify the full path of the source (which is `/` in my original answer). I'll add a clarification.

Comment: I think if you want to copy everything as symlink with one command only, you have to use cp -s like @hlovdal answer, `cp -rs /var/www/folder/ .` copies every subfolders files as symlink, not like `ln -s /var/www/folder/ .` who duplicated subfolders files on my computer.

Comment: If anyone needs that: hidden files can be symlinked in a second step with `ln -s /foo/.* /bar`.

Comment: great best answer

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
cd /foo
for f in *; do ln -s $PWD/$f /bar; done
```